# Axios Post Request Stalled

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am making a POST request with Axios within a for loop to create leads in mass.  The leads get created but the issue that I'm noticing is that even though I get a 200 response, in the network tab under timing, the requests are actually never finished, they just say "stalled".

Below is a screenshot of what I'm talking about
[image]

This can become a problem, because if I do other POST requests like this, not all the requests will go through.  I think I read somewhere that Google Chrome only allows up to 6 connections open or something like that.  If these requests are stalling, I can only assume that those connections are staying open, and that's what's causing this to happen.

So I guess my question is, what's the best way to put this POST request in a for loop without the requests stalling?  Should I make it asynchronous, and if so how would I do that with my code?

Here is my server.js

```js
app.get('/create*', (request, response) => {
    var baseurl = 'https://OURACC.nocrm.io/api/v2/'
    var apikey = 'APIKEY'

    var title = "";
    var description = "";
    var tags = [];
    var pathname = request.url; // retrieves the requested pathname (ie, /crm/path)

    pathname = pathname.split('?');
    pathname = pathname[0].split('/')
    var parameters = request.query.params;

    var path = pathname[2]; // gets request path for the crm

    title = parameters.title
    description = parameters.description
    tags = parameters.tags

    var params = {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        tags: tags
    }


    if(path === 'leads'){

           // console.log("Inside Lead Creation");
            axios.post(baseurl + path,
                params
            ,{
                headers: {'X-API-KEY': apikey, content_type: "json", accept: "application/json"} 
            }).then(function(res){
                console.log("Lead Created");
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.log("Error: " + error);
            }) 
    }

})
```

This is where I call it client side

```js
CreateLeads(){
        var prospects = this.state.Prospects;
        var description = "";
        var title = "";
        var tags = [];



        for(var i = 0; i < prospects.length; i++){
            tags = prospects[i].tags;
            title = prospects[i].leadName;
            description = "Business Name: " + prospects[i].businessName + "\n" +
                            "Customer Number: " + prospects[i].custNumber + "\n" +
                            "Corporate Name: " + prospects[i].corpName + "\n" +
                            "Corporate Contact Name: " + prospects[i].corpContName + "\n" +
                            "Corporate Phone: " + prospects[i].corpPhone + "\n" +
                            "Corporate Email: " + prospects[i].corpEmail + "\n" +
                            "Customer First Name: " + prospects[i].custFirst + "\n" +
                            "Customer Last Name: " + prospects[i].custLast + "\n" +
                            "Street: " + prospects[i].street + "\n" +
                            "City: " + prospects[i].city + "\n" +
                            "State: " + prospects[i].state + "\n" +
                            "Zip: " + prospects[i].zip + "\n" +
                            "Phone 1: " + prospects[i].phone + "\n" +
                            "Category: " + prospects[i].category;

            var data = {
                title: title,
                description: description,
                tags: tags,
            }

            console.log(data);
            $.get('/create/leads', {params: data}).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
            })
        }

    }
```

Comment: your server side code never uses response to send anything.

Comment: @HMR Oh, should I just put response.send(res)?

Comment: After console.log(response); add this response.send(response);

Comment: And after console.log(error); add this response.status(500).send(error);

Comment: @HMR Thanks!  That was exactly the issue.